Connecting 2 vertices in Geo Nodes
So im creating a grass blade and i need to make the blade have a point. I know the indexes and this is what i want to do: 
Really I just need to know if and how to connect two vertices using their indexes.
Edit: @StefLAncien gave me the solution to instead of deleting the extra vertices setting them to the same position as the center on and merging them.


A face along the edge would be the most ideal, my bad for not specifying

The simplest way might be not to delete the left and right top vertices with red cross, but to set their position to be the same as the top vertex in-between. Then a Merge by Distance node should remove duplicated faces and edges. Beware I have not try it !

@StefLAncien that worked perfectly thanks so much,

Could you please write the solution as an answer below so that you can mark it as "Accepted Answer" and the question will appear as solved? Thank you very much!

@StefLAncien gave me the solution to instead of deleting the extra vertices setting them to the same position as the center on and merging them:

The simplest way might be not to delete the left and right top
vertices with red cross, but to set their position to be the same as
the top vertex in-between. Then a Merge by Distance node should remove
duplicated faces and edges.

